# Can we set a priority for our application in spotlight search results?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, search, spotlight

I have an application developed and installed on my iphone. When I am searching with some letters of my application name, under search results my application is coming along with other results which matches the search term. Now I want to get my application on top of all search results. I am aware that I can change the spotlight preferences between categories(like contacts, applications, mail etc). But is there any way to set priorities between applications? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You change settings of the way the result are displayed so your app show up first? I really hope that this is not possible via code.

Comment: Are you wanting your app to show up first on JUST your phone? Or in the app store?

Comment: Hi Drew, I want it to be on the top of all apps in the user's iphone

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible. And how would it be implemented? Imagine two apps, both trying to be above all other apps. There's no way to resolve this.

Comment: Mike, I can agree with you. At least can we get on what basis the apple will provide priorities for apps while searching?